# Ajax function after form validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I'm using jQuery.validate() to validate a form.

I'm trying to execute a $.ajax function after the validation, but it doesn't work.

The structure of the code is:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){    
    if($("#form").valid() == true)
    {
        AJAX FUNCTION HERE, NOT WORKING
    }
});

$("#form").validate({
    VALIDATION HERE, IT WORKS
});
```

If I write the AJAX FUNCTION outside the validation code, it's works, but I need to process it after the form validation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: that is because your form is not validated.try displaying the value returned by valid()

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("#form").validate() == true`?

Comment: I put alert($("#form").valid()); in the code. When I fill out the form, the result is "true".

Comment: can you share teh ajax call you are trying to make

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){    
    if($("#form").valid() != true)
    {
        alert('This is not returning true but '+$("#form").valid() );
    }
    else{
        //Ajax Call goes Here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your click event add this:

```
var valid = $('#frm').valid();
            if (!valid) {
                return false;
            }
//ajax code here
```